BigQuery : update many rows at the same time with Python
I have a BigQuery table of more than 10k rows and I'm looking for a way to update its rows in a quicker way than one by one using the Python API.
What is the best way ? I thought about using asynchronous functions with the asyncio library of Python but is there an easier method ?

Just use a single UPDATE query that specifies the condition in the WHERE clause, e.g. UPDATE tablename SET col = new_value WHERE some_condition

Unfortunately this won't work because like this you can only update one row at a time when you have different values to set

See here for how to do it in MySQL. I don't know BQ, but I suspect it's similar.
